# sshd wont start at boot

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, startup

I just installed Debian 6, after reboot sshd stopped responding. 
I put the default config file but it not help. 
In the logs (/var/log/auth,syslog) no errors.
I think the problem is that sshd not start. How can I try to run it? maybe do something in the startup scripts?
Unfortunately I do not have physical access to my virtual machine, and can only reload it and view/edit the files in the filesystem.

[ added  ]

Oh, thanks all. I found the problem.

Added `/usr/sbin/sshd -e 2>/tmp/sshd_error` to `crontab`

And get: `/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/sshd: No such file or directory`

Vaguely I could not understand where to lost a binary file on a freshly installed machine and I could work without it.

But now another question: how can I restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start sshd by hand with `exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D` to see if sshd works in general. If it does, a `update-rc.d ssh defaults` should create the `init.d` symlinks as required.

Comment: I have no shell access to the server. Can only reload server and view/edit the files. Maybe I can write something in the startup scripts?

Comment: no shell access? oh oh... does the `/etc/init.d/ssh` script exist? If it does (and if it contains the `exec /usr/sbin/sshd` call), take a look into the `/etc/rc[0-6].d` directories if there's a symlink. if there's no symlink, you could try to copy the script into /etc/rc3.d/, rename it to `S16ssh` (for example) and see if it's executed after a reboot.

Comment: @vlad: IMHO the best solution would be to **re-install debian from scratch**. If `sshd` is missing completely, most likely its dependencies are missing, too. Maybe other vital components are also missing, so i think it doesn't make much sense trying to repair that system manually.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that it was a problem hosting company, they use a common packages (like sshd and etc) for all virtual machines and they have something broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can run [sshd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) in debug mode using the -d switch. This causes sshd to stay in the foreground and print messages to the console. You can increase the volume of log messages by adding more -d's

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

for normal logging

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

for lots of logging.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no shell access to the server. Can only reload server and view/edit the files.

Answer (score 1):

Set the log level to DEBUG in sshd configuration.

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

Comment: What kinds of debug messages will get printed, and where?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ssh isn't activated at boot? See if there are pointers in /etc/rc.d to /etc/init.d/ssh.
Alternatively, it may not start if the ssh main key is missing. Check if /etc/ssh/ssh_host*key are present.